# Matlab checking for a value in a database

Tags: python, sql, matlab, postgresql

I have the following Boolean statement in Python:

```
db_connection.query(
   'select storage_time from traces where id=' + trace_id
).dictresult()[0]['storage_time'] == None
```

It basically checks if there is a value in `storage_time` and I would like to do the same thing in Matlab, but I can't find anything equivalent to None.

Could you please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: I would look at a trace_id where you know this is true in python and see what the query returns in matlab

Answer (score 5):

Equivalent to None values from Python are NULLs. And since you connect to your database
via Matlab Database Toolbox, you need to specify how NULL values retrieved from database
are to be presented in Matlab. This may be done by setting of `'NullNumberRead'`
via calling of `setdbprefs` function from Matlab Database Toolbox. For instance, you can do this so

```
setdbprefs('NullNumberRead','NaN')
```

or so

```
setdbprefs('NullNumberRead','0')
```

Unfortunately, there is no guarantee that the NULL representation value specified by this way won't be confused
with real non-NULL values obtained as a result of your query (it is your own responsibility in this case to
guarantee the query always do not contain NaNs or zeros, respectively, among non-NULL values in its results).
But if you have to connect to PostgreSQL, as far as I know, there exists at least one Matlab and PostgreSQL connector that
respects NULLs in a fully consistent manner. This is a high-performance PostgreSQL client library [PgMex](http://pgmex.alliedtesting.com/).

In PostgreSQL both a value itself and the value elements can be NULL (for array types). This makes a representation of NULLs in Matlab less trivial than expected.

To illustrate the way PgMex uses to represent NULLs in Matlab, let us consider the following example.  Suppose you have to retrieve results for a query returning one field `myfield` of `float8[]` type with two tuples. And suppose the value of `myfield` for the first tuple equals to NULL as itself, while for the second tuple the corresponding value equals `{0,NULL,NaN}`. Results are obtained as follows
(we assume that the argument of the very first command `connect` below is corrected properly and that the table `mytable` containing
`myfield` of `float8[]` type among its fields already exists within the respective database):

```
% Create the database connection
dbConn=com.allied.pgmex.pgmexec('connect',[...
    'host=<yourhost> dbname=<yourdb> port=<yourport> '...
    'user=<your_postgres_username> password=<your_postgres_password>']);

pgResult=com.allied.pgmex.pgmexec('exec',dbConn,...
    'select myfield from mytable'); % perform the query

SMyField=com.allied.pgmex.pgmexec('getf',pgResult,...
    '%float8[]',0); % retrieve the results
```

Here `SMyField` is a structure with three fields: `valueVec`, `isNullVec` and `isValueNullVec`.
`isValueNullVec` equals a column logical array `[true;false]`, that is the entire value for the first tuple equals NULL,
while the value for the second tuple does not equal NULL as itself. `isNullVec` equals the following column cell array:
`{[];[false,true,false]}`. By this way it is possible to indicate that only the second element of the array being the value
of `myfield` for the second tuple is NULL. At last, `valueVec` equals to the column cell array `{[];[0 0 NaN]}`. Only
the first and the third elements of the second cell are relevant, in contrast to the second element of this array.
This is because `isNullVec` clearly indicates that this second element is NULL, so this zero value does not matter
(some default value is chosen for each particular data type).

What concerns your example, the respective code in Matlab may be the following (we assume that `dbConn` obtained as above already exists
as well as that the query below is correct with `storage_time` field of `timestamp` type and the variable trace_id being already defined):

```
pgResult=com.allied.pgmex.pgmexec('exec',dbConn,...
    ['select storage_time from traces where id=' + trace_id]); % perform the query
SStorageTime=com.allied.pgmex.pgmexec('getf',pgResult,...
    '%timestamp',0); % retrieve the results
% check that the value for the first tuple is not NULL
isStorageTime=~SStorageTime.isValueNullVec(1);
```

Hence it is sufficient to check only `isValueNullVec`.

EDIT: There are free academic licenses for [PgMex](http://pgmex.alliedtesting.com/).

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB's Database Toolbox has preferences how to handle NULL values. Depending on those settings you can get different values. See [SETDBPREFS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/setdbprefs.html#bq42vl0) for details. You can [change preferences in GUI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/working-with-preferences.html) as well.

By default you will get NaN if you read the data as numeric, and 'NULL' strings if you read as strings. In the first case for numbers check for NaN with [ISNAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) function.

```
null_idx = isnan(fetcheddata);
```

For strings use [STRCMP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html):

```
null_idx= strcmp(upper(fetcheddata), 'NULL');
```

In addition, if you fetch the data as cell array, you may need to deal with them with [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) or convert to matrix with [CELL2MAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Matlab idiom is usually to use the `isempty()` function.

```
isempty(somefunction(someargument))
```

returns `true` if `somefunction(someargument)` returns any empty result, and `false` otherwise.

I have not worked with the Matlab DB toolbox much, so I'm not sure what the full translation of your Python statement is.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this query you can check for `True` or `False` in instead of None:

```
trace_id_exists = db_connection.query("""\
    select exists (
        select 1
        from traces
        where id = %s
        ) "exists"
    """ % trace_id
).dictresult()[0]['exists']

if trace_id_exists:
    ...
```

You could also return something else like 1 or 0.